# In Struts2, dynamically generate form element name using a member value

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2, ognl

My requirement: In Struts 2, dynamically generate form element name by using member value.

I had tried with: `<s:textarea name="employee_<s:property value='employeeNumber'/>"/>`

Resulting code in web browser: `<textarea name="employee_&lt;s:property value='employeeNumber'/&gt;"></textarea>`

My expectation in web browser code: `<textarea name="employee_101"></textarea>`. `101` as an `employeeNumber` is only used for demonstration only.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: @Braj et al. Note: I want dynamically generated form element 'name'.

Comment: @Braj Not a duplicate. They are used scoped variables, that is not required for this question.

Comment: @Braj request attributes are not in the value stack, and this question doesn' expose any of the request attributes and not asking `attr` to access them.

Comment: @RomanC how to revert my action?

Comment: @Braj It's not possible on SO, but you can upvote, it lowers chances to close the question by reviewers.

Comment: @Braj Next time, please do not delete comment as follow-up comments by others become out of context for readers. It's fine to misunderstand and a follow-up comment on same would make things clear and keep thread clean.

Comment: @Sannidhi OK I'll take care it next time. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts2 you can always use OGNL expression in the Struts tag's attribute. Just provide the value from the value stack. You should know that the action bean is on top of it, and having a getter for `employeeNumber` should return desired value `101`.

```
<s:textarea name="employee_%{employeeNumber}"/>
```

Also be aware of Struts doesn't allow nested tags in the attributes in favor of OGNL.

Answer (score 1):

try this,it working fine.

MyAction.class

```
private int property_value;

public int getProperty_value() {
    return 6;
}

public void setProperty_value(int property_value) {
    this.property_value = property_value;
}
```

result.jsp

```
<s:set var="xyz" value="property_value"  />
<s:textarea name="emap_%{#xyz}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. I'm aware of your suggestion(I should have mentioned in OP, my apologies) as a solution, but didn't implement as there are few variables which need to be generated, in a loop. That creates lot many temporary variables. Up-voted your answer.